# Google Play doesn’t display supported screen sizes of the android apk properly

Tags: android

I have created four different apk of my android app for supporting four different screen size (small, normal, large and xlarge) devices. But after uploading those apk on google play ,  its displaying that apk is supported for **small-xlarge** screen **though the apk is created for small screen size device** using

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  I have used android API level 4 
.  **Same problem is also occuring for other uploaded apk of small & normal size screen device.**

Could any one give any suggestion for solving this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

[`<compatible-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) is the way to go for targeting individual screen sizes (as per [Distributing to Specific Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)).

Comment: An error is being generated when <compatible-screens> is used. the error is -----                                                                                                                                        Multiple annotations found at this line:
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'screenDensity' in package
'android'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'screenSize' in package
'android'

Comment: Change the sdk with which you build the application to API level 9. (it will not affect the functionality)

Comment: thanks a lot. it's working. But if I have to use api lavel 9, how will I give support for the devices with previous api level ? Suppose for api level 8 .......

Comment: Set the `minSdkVersion` attribute to the lowest API level you want to support.